# Rotate the inner box as I rotate the outer box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have two boxes inside a `box-wrapper`. As I rotate the box, the `inner` box should also rotate. But, the problem is, the inner box doesn't rotate.

Note: I have to make both boxes be `position:absolute` as siblings.

```
<div class="box-wrapper">
  <div class="inner">
   RED BOX
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  </div>
</div>
```

Please check the complete code below:

https://jsfiddle.net/1p9b0q5c/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code like as follows,

```js
$(function() {
  // Prepare extra handles
  var nw = $("<div>", {
    class: "ui-rotatable-handle"
  });
  var ne = nw.clone();
  var se = nw.clone();
  /*
  You can also combine this plugin with the jQuery UI built-in resizable() and draggable(), although the latter works best when applied to a container with the rotatable inside it. See the Demo page for some examples.
  */
  // Assign Draggable
  $('.box-wrapper').draggable({
    cancel: ".ui-rotatable-handle"
  });
  // Assign Rotatable
  $('.box').resizable().rotatable({rotate:function(event, ui){
    var angle = ui.angle.current;
   $('.inner').css('transform','rotate('+angle+'rad)');
  }});
  // Assign coordinate classes to handles
  $('.box div.ui-rotatable-handle').addClass("ui-rotatable-handle-sw");
  nw.addClass("ui-rotatable-handle-nw");
  ne.addClass("ui-rotatable-handle-ne");
  se.addClass("ui-rotatable-handle-se");
  // Assign handles to box
  $(".box").append(nw, ne, se);
  // Assigning bindings for rotation event
  $(".box div[class*='ui-rotatable-handle-']").bind("mousedown", function(e) {
    $('.box').rotatable("instance").startRotate(e);
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background:transparent;
  margin: 27px;
  position: absolute;
}

.ui-rotatable-handle {
  background: url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.ui.rotatable/1.0.1/rotate.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  position: absolute;
}

.ui-rotatable-handle-sw {
  bottom: -27px;
  left: -27px;
}

.ui-rotatable-handle-nw {
  top: -27px;
  left: -27px;
}

.ui-rotatable-handle-se {
  bottom: -27px;
  right: -27px;
}

.ui-rotatable-handle-ne {
  top: -27px;
  right: -27px;
}
.inner{
    background: red;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left:43px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.ui.rotatable/1.0.1/jquery.ui.rotatable.min.js"></script>

<div class="box-wrapper">
    <div class="inner">
      RED BOX
    </div>
   <div class="box">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm slow to answer :) I've changed something similar to yours, but I think you can center the `inner` box and add the following styles: `top: 50%;left:50%;transform:translate(-50%,-50%);`

Comment: @Shijin , Thank you but  inner and outer box should be treated as `siblings` and not as child-parent divs.

Comment: @smzapp The better way is this, otherwise, you can rotate manually on the rotate callback

Comment: @Shijin , Yeah, that's the problem, How to automatically rotate the inner box the same with outer box.

Comment: After executing `$('.box').resizable().rotatable()`, it only works on `.box` box

Comment: $('.box').resizable().rotatable({rotate:function(event, ui){
   
  }}); You can use the callback like this

Comment: @Shijin, yeah. I also have that including start and stop function. Though this is not yet the solution, but thank you for your effort. Hopefully somebody can still look into that code and help me fix.

Comment: @Shijin Thank you for helping me on this question. I would highly appreciate it if you could help me on another question related to this one. Here is the link. Thank you so much. :) 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58946077/rotatable-non-zero-angle-in-jquery